# ASP.net background-image doesn't show up

Tags: css, asp.net, background-image

My background image won't show itself in my asp.net website.

The code's I tried are:

```
body {
    background-image:url('Assets/Images/background.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

background-image:url('~Assets/Images/background.png')
```

Comment: Got any error in console?

Comment: I've already fixed it myself, because I was using '~/Assets/images/background.png' he was searching something that didn't existed. '../Images/background.png' fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

```
background-image:url('~/Assets/Images/background.png')
```

You are missing /